# Facing issue while chunking then merging the jar files

Tags: java, file, jar, chunked-encoding, chunked

I have one jar file for example apache-cassandra-3.11.6.jar.
Firstly i split/chunked into mutiple jars like below :

apache-cassandra1.jar
apache-cassandra2.jar
apache-cassandra3.jar
apache-cassandra4.jar
apache-cassandra5.jar
apache-cassandra6.jar

Then i reassemble them again into new Jar file i.e apache-cassandra_Merged.jar.
Now the problem comes.

When i compare the original jar file i.e apache-cassandra-3.11.6.jar with new Jar file i.e apache-cassandra_Merged.jar. then it is not matching.

The newly created jar file which is apache-cassandra_Merged.jar, it's size also reduced.

Please find below my code for your reference :

```
/// Chunking/spliting into mutiple jars
Path path = Paths.get("/Original_Jar/apache-cassandra-3.11.6.jar");
byte [] data = Files.readAllBytes(path); // Will read all bytes at once
```

Now divide total bytes into equal part and then write in each small  jars one by one.

```
int count = 0;
for(byte[] rangeData : Arrays.copyOfRange(data, rangeSTART, rangeEND)){
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = new FileOutputStream("/Cassandra_Image/Chunked_Jar/apache-cassandra"+count+".jar");
        fileOutputStream1.write(rangeData);
}
```

//Merging back to one jar
For merging i used the same way. Created array of byte for each small/chunked jars and written into FileOutputStream("/Merged_Jar/apache-cassandra_Merged.jar") one by one.

Please let me know if i should use some other method/algorithm to split jar and reassemble it again which will make sure the originality of data after chunking and merging as well.

Note : Actually i want to transfer the jars to any server/directory where i should transfer a jar with limited size so for big size jars i need to split into small jars and send them one by one and then again reassemble them in target directory/place and it should be as original jar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to create a fat jar file which contains all dependencies along with your application ?

Comment: Actually i want to transfer the jars to any server/directory where i should transfer a jar with limited size so for big size jars i need to split into small jars and send them one by one and then again reassemble them in target directory/place and it should be as original jar. I hope it will clarifies your query ? @Sambit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue with shell scripting.
Written below code in my shell script file and run through my java code.

```
split -b 1000000 src.jar target.jar
cat src.jaraa src.jarab src.jarac src.jarad src.jarae > merged.jar
```

And compare with any algorithm like sha256 checksum will work fine and it shows equal. and size also equal.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer, but I provide as an information for you. Java also provides pack format where you can compress the jar files and then you can uncompress using unpack.
The tool is called **pack200**.

**How to compress**

```
<java_location>...\jre\lib>pack200 -J-Xmx256m small.jar.gz big.jar
```

**How to uncompress**

```
<java_location>...\jre\lib>unpack200 small.jar.gz big.jar
```

You can refer the following links.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/pack200.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/unpack200.html

Comment: Thanks @Sambit but file type can be anything txt, png, pdf, jar, mp3, mov etc.. so I need to go ahead with splitting approach for now.